# How to replace the current rows with previous rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series

I have data frame df as below and I want to impute the zeroes with previous four rows.

I tried below code but did not work for me

```
       df.loc [7:11] = df.loc [3:7]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution should be change by convert to numpy array for avoid index alignment:

```
df.loc[7:10] = df.loc[3:6].to_numpy()
print (df)
    XYZ
0    12
1    23
2    11
3    34
4    45
5    54
6    34
7    34
8    45
9    54
10   34
11  100
12   12
13   15
```

Another idea is replace `0` with [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'XYZ':[12,23,11,34,45,54,34,0,0,0,0,100,12,15]})

df['XYZ'] = df['XYZ'].mask(df['XYZ'].eq(0), df['XYZ'].shift(4))
print (df)
    XYZ
0    12
1    23
2    11
3    34
4    45
5    54
6    34
7    34
8    45
9    54
10   34
11  100
12   12
13   15
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
df.loc[7:11, 'XYZ'] = df.loc[3:7, 'XYZ'].tolist()
```